# Server error in '/' Application Visual Studio 2015 community

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Need your help on this.I'm a newbie to the C# visual studio domain.
I was going over the tutorial on Microsoft site to create App and deploy on Azure. Here is the link below:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/

After completing every single step .I have this annoying error message that keeps popping up whenever I try to access/ login-in - by using the google account or using the default user name and password on the site. [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAeu2.png)

I've gone line by line checking my steps and codes ;my azure server, app and database is running perfectly. Google API and app is running - no errors. 
On my local machine it is works fine. But, when I publish the code to Azure - the home page comes up and I can navigate to the login page but - I just can't login-in using the google AuthOut nor the default login page using the default credentials on line.

For the life of me -  can't understand why its not working. Need help people.

Answer (score 1):

The error  means that your site is trying to talk to your database (SQL Server) but it can't connect to it.  You probably don't have a SQL server database setup.

Look at step 11 in the instructions:

> 11.Select Create new server, enter a server name, user name, and password.

I'm guessing that you didn't create the database when you were creating your web app.

Comment: I did create my SQL database on Azure - it's been up and running.

Comment: What was the solution?